# Making text "non-readable"

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am in a weird situation, in where I have to put my name and contact information on a webpage and I think it is fine, as long as the text can't be read by robots, copied, etc.

Basically what I want is a text block that looks like normal text, but behaves like an image. I cannot, however, use an actual image because the background and other stuff is preventing me to.

Is there some way to overcome this issue of mine? I was thinking I could type everything backwards and use that one control character that reverses the text direction... or maybe I could add invisible letters in between the real ones somehow, so that the text remains readable by humans, but not by site crawlers.

Edit: To clarify, it would not be the end of the world if some smart bot really wanted to crawl my information. I just want to make it hard enough, so that the first random bot that crawls the site will not straight away get my information.

Edit 2: Great and interesting answers. Might need those ideas elsewhere as well!

Comment: that's not how websites work

Comment: As far as I know you won't be able to do that, however I think you might be able to prevent bots from crawling the site with .htaccss file. But that will hurt your ranking probably.

Comment: Pseudo-elements would probably achieve this, but it seems foolish to put information you don't want bots to access on the internet. And if the bot can use JavaScript the pseudo-element's text is accessible anyway.

Comment: maybe i could ,maybe i could be a millionaire but that's not how life works

Comment: @Ljubisa Rest of the page should of course remain "unharmed", so a .htaccess will not probably work.

Comment: Difficult to see a technical reason preventing you from placing an image wherever you like on the page ...

Comment: @Vohuman As in the steps to make my contact information uncrawlable should not affect anything else.

Comment: @AlexK. The formatting of the text changes too much and would require too much work to make the image work.

Comment: @Piwwoli - did you consider using media queries to make multiple [background] images which can vary on different screen sizes?

Comment: One option is drawing text on canvas by using JavaScript.

Comment: @andi Yeah, but I mean the text formatting is designed by some guy and it makes no sense, but he says it looks great that way and that's why it has to be just like the way he designed it. Classic.

Answer (score 2):

xyz@example.com:

```
<span style="unicode-bidi:bidi-override; direction: rtl;">
moc.elpmaxe@zyx
</span>
```

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-e-mail-address-obfuscation-actually-work

However, you need to be careful. 
When you reverse a string, e.g.  `"Les Mise\u0301rables"` as `"selbare\u0301siM seL"`. This should render just like

> selbarésiM seL

, not like

> selbaŕesiM seL

(note the position of the accent). If you just do `new string("bla".ToCharArray().Reverse())`, then this will mess up your string, which is, to use the precise technical term, WRONG.

So this is how to properly reverse a string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

public static class Test
{
    private static IEnumerable<string> GraphemeClusters(this string s)      
    {
        var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s);
        while(enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            yield return (string)enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
    private static string ReverseGraphemeClusters(this string s) {
        return string.Join("", s.GraphemeClusters().Reverse().ToArray());
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "Les Mise\u0301rables";
        var r = s.ReverseGraphemeClusters();
        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I also took the invisible letter thing to a test and made a class like so: `.i { letter-spacing: 0; width: 0; font-size: 0 }` which allows me to spam my contact information with `<span>` elements and gibberish. This has the added bonus, should someone select and copy the text, the text copied will be gibberish :)

Comment: Injecting this markup via javascript, and possibly base64 or png encoding the source are two additional steps of obfuscation

Comment: @ Piwwoli: The unicode-bidi CSS property together with the direction property relates to the handling of bidirectional text in a document.If a block of text contains both left-to-right and right-to-left text, then the user-agent uses a complex Unicode algorithm to decide how to display the text. This property overrides this algorithm and allows the developer to control the text embedding. bidi-override
For inline elements this creates an override. For block container elements this creates an override for inline-level descendants not within another block container element.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
.hiddenemail::before{
    content: "myemailtohide"
}
.hiddenemail::after {
    content: "emaildomain.com"
}

<p class="hiddenemail">@</p>
```

The pseudo classes :before and :after aren't in the dom and shouldn't be visible to robots.
The reason why i splittet the address in two parts it's to prevent the sniff trough some regex of the plain CSS file.

Comment: That alone probably might not work, but it is a great idea and an extra layer of obfuscation!

Comment: It should work in the large majority of situations, i think it is anyway better than other metods that, even if in "tricky" forms, put anyway the address (or whatever) in the DOM...

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with requiring users to interact with the page to reveal your address then you can use recaptcha's [mailhide](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/apikey).  It requires the user to click a "show me the address" link/button, which then tests them with a captcha.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is that the text needs to be human-readable straight away when the page is loaded, so it needs to be obfuscated in some other level.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear: If it's on the web as text, bots can read it. There's absolutely no way around that. You can use a robots.txt file to ask them not to read it, but malicious bots will ignore that. You can hide it with Javascript, but modern bots can execute scripts. Simply put, what you're asking for can't be done.

I don't really see what your problem is with using an image. A bit of transparency on a PNG will allow your backgrounds to show through just fine. Having said that, bear in mind that spam bots can and do use OCR to read text from images as well; if you're trying to avoid getting picked up by spammers, your only real option is not to publish your details in the first place.

If you're trying to obfuscate it to make it harder to read, the closest you're going to get is to an SVG image with text characters built up manually using vectors, and not mapping to a known font. The spammers' OCR scripts may struggle with that, plus it'll have the advantage of being scalable and with good transparency for your background. But it is overkill really.

Comment: Image won't work mainly because the text is so weirdly formatted and changes on different screen sizes, unfortunately.

Comment: @Piwwoli if you use SVG, the image wont be distorted, but then theres the browser compatibility there. There are also bots that have the ability to read images, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a website that provides good information on [protecting your number and email from spambots](http://websitehelpers.com/spam/). The recommended method, although still susceptible, is to implement using javascript.

Regardless which method you implement, your information (when published on the web) is harvestable.